# Creating Multiple Nuget Packages from a Visual Studio Solution

Tags: nuget, teamcity, nuget-spec

I have a Visual Studio 2015 Solution which contains multiple projects. Some of these projects reference each other. Example

```
Solution
   Project A
   Project B - references Project A
```

On teamcity, I want to create nuget packages for each of these projects, such that when Nuget is generating a package from Project B, I want it to be aware that Project A has a Nuget package and reference that Nuget package instead of having to use the -IncludeReferencedProjects flag.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Using VS 2017 (or the `dotnet` cli tooling - labelled ".net core SDK") you can build libraries using the new sdk-based csproj tooling that have exactly that behaviour: Each project will produce a separate NuGet package and project references will be replaced with NuGet dependencies.

To do that, use the .NET Standard Library project template (or `dotnet new lib` on the commandline) - if you want to build your libraries for the .NET Framework, change the content of the `<TargetFramework>`element in the `csproj` file from `netstandard1.4` to e.g. `net461` (there just isn't a .NET Framework library template (yet?) that uses the new project system / tooling).

To build nuget packages you then use `dotnet pack` or `msbuild /t:Pack`in your CI build (there is a TeamCity plugin for building with the .net core tools as well. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core/).

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks...I forgot to mention that I am using VS 2015

Comment: Well.. if you want that as an easy feature, that's a reason to upgrade. Nuget <4 / vs2015 solutions would require hand-editing nuspec files or writing scripts to generate them which is a pain to set up and maintain.